# Help understanding the chromatic numbers of the planes upper bound.

Tags: graph-theory, proof-explanation, coloring, plane-geometry

I've been studying the [Chromtic number of the plane](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hadwiger%E2%80%93Nelson_problem) and it shows that a hexagonal tiling of seven colors shows that 7 is an upper bound. [image: 7 color tiling]

I couldn't actually follow the argument that proves this is an upper bound.

My problem is why can't the same argument be made by a tiling like
[image: 4 coloring] or [image: alternate tiling] which both only have four colors.

What makes the original tessellation an upper bound but not the four color one's?

Comment: How are you using the other two diagrams in reference to the Hadwiger-Nelson problem? Can you please indicate on your diagrams what one unit of length is. All reasonable measures of one unit that I apply to your two extra diagrams result in two or more points of distance 1 having the same color.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the first diagram, take the unit of distance to be slightly greater than the diameter of a hexagon. Then it's clear that two points of the same color can't be exactly one unit apart: if they're in the same hexagon, they're too close, and ***if they're in different hexagons of the same color, then they're too far apart***.

Now look at your hexagonal tiling. What are you going to take as the unit distance? It must be greater then the diameter of a hexagon, or else two vertices in the same hexagon will be a unit distance apart. But the distance between two nearby blue hexagons is less than the diameter of a hexagon; so, in order to keep from having two points in nearby blue hexagons a unit distance apart, the unit distance must be greater than the diameter of the union of two nearby blue hexagons; and so forth.